# Django: cómo bajar una imagen de una url y guardarla en un modelo

Tags: python, django

Tengo una lista de urls de imágenes que tengo que guardar en modelos que tengo de imagenes. Puedo bajar la imagen pero cuando se la guardo al modelo me dice
`'PngImageFile' object has no attribute 'read'`

```
import requests
from PIL import Image
import io
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
from api.models import Img

response = requests.get(url)
image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(response.content))
name = "prueba." + image.format
image_tmp = InMemoryUploadedFile(
    image, None, name, image.format, image.size, None)
img = Img()
img.title = "un titulo"
name = "prueba.{}".format(image.format)
img.image_original.save(name, image_tmp)
```

Mi modelo para imagenes:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

from imagekit.models import ImageSpecField


class Img(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=600, blank=True, null=True,)
    upload_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, )
    image_original = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d', default="images/default/noimages.png", )
    image_compress = ImageSpecField(
        source='image_original',
        format='JPEG', options={'quality': 60}, )

    def image_tag(self):
        """ This method is useful for the django admin. It allows you to see a thumbnail"""
        return mark_safe(
            "<img src='{}' width='100' height='100'/>".format(self.image_original.url)
        )
    image_tag.short_description = 'Image'

    def __str__(self):
        return "{!r} - RelativePath: {}>".format(self.title, self.image_original)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Image'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Images'
```

Comment: Puedes poner el modelo creado para las imagenes?

Comment: Sí, ahí lo agregué!

Answer (score 0):

Intenta pasándole el nombre del archivo al momento de guardar la imagen:

```
img.image_original.save(name, image_tmp)
```

El primer parámetro del método [`save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.save) es el nombre del archivo.

Comment: Cuando pegué el código lo formatié para que se entienda y me comí un par de cosas. Ahí lo agregué el nombre. No es lo que me está tirando esa excepción que indique.

Comment: @eduzen  tal vez ayude si pegas el Traceback completo